# Segmentation fault in C? Arrays, pointers, functions

Tags: c, codeblocks, segmentation-fault

Hi due to my lack of knowledge in C (second year in college). Compiler ate my code and built the app. But after accepting first value - numOfIntegers it stops working and debugging tells that the segmentation has been failed. SIGSEGV.
How to fix that?

There is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

/* -----------------------------------------
    Program: Question 1
    Author: Maggot #9
    Email: maggot99999@gmail.com
    ID: B00076450
    Date: 16 September 2015
    Purpose: Who knows?
   ------------------------------------------ */

void wait(int);
void controlMenu(int, int[]);
int sumOfIntegers(int, int[]);
int avgOfIntegers(int, int[]);
int prodOfIntegers(int, int[]);
int minInteger(int, int[]);
int maxInteger(int, int[]);


const char * getName (int value)
{

  static char * arrayName[] = {"first","second","third", "fourth",
    "fifth","sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth"};

  static char badValue[] = "unknown";

  if (value<10 && value>=0)
    return arrayName[value];
  else
    return badValue;
}

int getValue(int numOfInteger)
{
  int value;
  wait(100);
  printf("Please enter %s the value:", getName(numOfInteger));
  scanf("%d",&value);

  return value;
}


void prepare(int * numOfIntegers)
{
  wait(300);
  printf("Hey again that C stupid lang\n\n");
  wait(200);
  printf("Please enter how many values you want to put: ");
  scanf("%d",numOfIntegers);
  return;
}


void initialize(int numOfIntegers,int* arrayNum[])
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<(numOfIntegers); i++)
    arrayNum[i] = getValue(i);

  wait(500);
  printf("\nPlease enter press any button to continue");
  wait(100);
  getch();
  wait(600);
  system("cls");
  wait(200);
  return;
}


int main()
{
  int numOfIntegers;
  prepare(&numOfIntegers);
  int arrayNum[numOfIntegers];
  initialize(numOfIntegers, &arrayNum[numOfIntegers]);
  controlMenu(numOfIntegers, &arrayNum[numOfIntegers]);
  return 0;
}


void controlMenu(int numOfIntegers, int arrayNum[])
{
  int i;
  char chooseNum;
  printf("Please choose any of the following:\n\n1. The integers accepted\n2. The sum of the integers\n3. The average of the integers\n4. The product of the integers\n5. The smallest integer\n6. The largest integer\n0. Exit menu\n");
  while(1)
  {
    chooseNum = getch();
    switch(chooseNum)
    {
      case '0':
        return;
      case '1':
        printf("\n>>> The integers are:");
        for(i=0; i<(numOfIntegers); i++)
          {
            printf("\n>>> The %s is %d", getName((i+1)), arrayNum[i]);
          }
        break;

      case '2':
        printf("\n>>> The sum of integers is: %d", sumOfIntegers(numOfIntegers, &arrayNum[numOfIntegers]));
        break;

      case '3':
        printf("\n>>> The average of integers is: %d", avgOfIntegers(numOfIntegers, &arrayNum[numOfIntegers]));
        break;

      case '4':
        printf("\n>>> The product of integers is: %d", prodOfIntegers(numOfIntegers, &arrayNum[numOfIntegers]));
        break;

      case '5':
        printf("\n>>> The smallest integer is: %d", minInteger(numOfIntegers, &arrayNum[numOfIntegers]));
        break;

      case '6':
        printf("\n>>> The largest integer is: %d", maxInteger(numOfIntegers, &arrayNum[numOfIntegers]));
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
  }
}


int sumOfIntegers(int numOfIntegers,int arrayNum[])
{
  int sum=0;

  for(int i=0; i<(numOfIntegers); i++)
    sum += arrayNum[i];

  return sum;
}


int avgOfIntegers(int numOfIntegers, int arrayNum[])
{
  int average=0;

  average = sumOfIntegers(numOfIntegers, arrayNum[numOfIntegers])/numOfIntegers;

  return average;
}


int prodOfIntegers(int numOfIntegers, int arrayNum[])
{
  int i,product=0;

  for(i=0; i<(numOfIntegers); i++)
    product *= arrayNum[i];

  return product;
}


int minInteger(int numOfIntegers, int arrayNum[])
{
  int i,smallest=0;
  smallest = arrayNum[0];

  for(i=1; i<(numOfIntegers); i++)
    {
      if(smallest>arrayNum[i])
        smallest=arrayNum[i];
      else
        continue;
    }

  return smallest;
}


int maxInteger(int numOfIntegers, int arrayNum[])
{
  int i,largest=0;
  largest = arrayNum[0];

  for(i=1; i<(numOfIntegers); i++)
    {
      if(largest<arrayNum[i])
        largest=arrayNum[i];
      else
        continue;
    }

  return largest;
}


void wait(int ms)
{
  Sleep(ms);
  return;
}
```

Comment: These warnings certainly showing up when compiling should give you a good view of what your code is like. By debugging, you should figure out which line (or at least which function) in particular segfaults.

Comment: @cad it doesnt show anything about what function may have a problem..

Comment: Dunno what debugging means to you but I mean stepping through the code by gdb, looking at register values, etc.

Comment: @cad Yes. But how u suppose to use the debugger in codeblocks when it barely works. He didn't even teach how to use it yet. When I showed him what are u doing he said u should not know that.
I had the experience to use VS and i like it! But my lecturer said to me use the same software. :/

Comment: Alright, didn't you are in the "learning phase."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see this fault in `getName()` which will access memory beyond the array bounds

```
if (value>10 || value<1)
    return arrayName[value];
```

I believe you are using the wrong test, try

```
if (value <= 10 && value > 0)
    return arrayName[value-1];
```

assuming `value` is in the range `1`..`10` as the textual array implies.

2) a fault in `GetValue` where you input into `numOfInteger` but `return value`, which is uninitialised.

3) in `prepare` the statement

```
scanf("%d",&numOfIntegers);
```

will not pass the input value back to the caller. You should have either passed a pointer to the variable, or returned the value input.

But there might be a lot else wrong. Build your program step by step, checking and trying to break it as you go (with absurd input). Pay attention to compiler warnings - the second fault I listed will generate one.

**EDIT** okay... let's examine function `prepare` which after removing noise is

```
void prepare(int numOfIntegers)
{
    scanf("%d",&numOfIntegers);
    return;
}
```

This inputs a value to the function parameter that was passed. This is legal, since you can use a function argument in the same way you can a local variable (perhaps subject to `const` qualification).

Although it's not a coding error, it does not achieve anything. 1) you usually pass an argument like this to be used by the function in some way, perhaps in its limits and/or in its prompt. 2) Altering the argument like this will not find its way back to the caller.

Here are two ways to deal with this.

A) the function returns the input value

```
int prepare(void)
{
    int value;
    scanf("%d", &value);    // the address of value
    return value;
}

...

int input = prepare();
printf("%d\n", input);
```

B) the function takes a pointer argument

```
void prepare(int *value)
{
    scanf("%d", value);     // value is already a pointer
}

...

int input;
prepare(&input);
printf("%d\n", input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. You were kinda right I would prefer c++ or c# more than c. And your bloody wrong about my attitude. This question was to accept to 2 int and do 5 answers from it probably all in main function.
But I want to get better in programming and make my own higher requirements to questions.

P.S. Got the best programming 1 CA and Exam result in the first year :D

Comment: Good for you Kaspar, but blaming the tools you have to work with that other people like... I'm the other way, I explored C++ but it always seemed to want the inheritance the other way up from what I was doing.

Comment: Soo how about the pointer you talked about? Still struggling in using them. Would appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @KasparSiricenko I have expanded my answer.

Comment: Hmmm. So you put an address as an argument. And then use the address as a pointer to scan the pointer and it will change the value in the address rather than the value itself. I get it right? 
I'm still confused. Btw I heard that buffer is much preferable than the pointer,  but he did not explain why. Well, at least now I have a very useful tip for this kind of situations. Cheers to you! :D

Comment: @KasparSiricenko "hands on" is the way to do it. Whether its coding, or a ball game, you go in there and try things out!